# Display Join Records Data in order of they created in Postgresql and Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have three tables in  postgresql database:

1. Members

   - id
   - first_name
   - last_name
   - created_at
2. Payments (Like Debit)

   - id
   - member_id
   - amount
   - created_at
   - type
3. Fees (Like Credit)

   - id
   - member_id
   - amount
   - created_at
   - type

I would like to show them in a single view say billing statements:
and I used following queries:

```
select * from members as t1 left join payments as t2 on (t1.id=t2.member_id) left join fees as t3 on (t1.id=t3.member_id)
```

and it shows me following results:

```
id | Amount | created_at | Type
1   100      25-12-2013   Fee
2   100      29-12-2013   Fee
3   100      25-12-2013   Payment
4   100      23-12-2013   Payment
```

But issue is that it shows first fees record and then payments while I need it should be order by created_at and it should be like below:

```
id | Amount | created_at | Type
1   100      23-12-2013   Payment
2   100      25-12-2013   Fee
3   100      25-12-2013   Payment
4   100      29-12-2013   Fee
```

Here is details of models:

```
class Fee < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :member_id,:fee_type,:amount,:reason,:details,:date

  # Setup relations with relative models
  belongs_to :member

  # Validates rule here
  validates_numericality_of :member_id,:fee_type,:amount

  validates :reason,
    :format => {:with => /^[-a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+$/ },
    :length => {:maximum => 255},
    :presence =>true
  validates :details,
    :format => {:with => /^[-a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+$/ },
    :length => {:maximum => 255},
    :allow_blank =>true
  validates :amount,
    :presence => true
  validates :member_id,
    :presence => true
  validates :date,
    :presence => true

  # Search start here
  self.per_page = 10

end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :member_id,:payment_category_id,:payment_type_id,:payment_date,:amount,:notes,:is_send_email,:last_sent,:date_deposite
  # Setup relations with relative models 
  belongs_to :payment_type
  belongs_to :payment_category
  belongs_to :member

  # Validates rule here
  validates_numericality_of :member_id,:payment_category_id,:payment_type_id,:amount

  validates :notes,
    :format => {:with => /^[-a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+$/ },
    :length => {:maximum => 255},
    :allow_blank =>true
  validates :amount,
    :presence => true,
    :length => {:maximum => 15}
  validates :member_id,
    :presence => true
  validates :payment_date,
    :presence => true

  # Pagiination start here
  self.per_page = 10

end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :payment, dependent: :destroy, -> { order :created_at }
  has_many :fee, dependent: :destroy, -> { order :created_at }
  has_many :events, :through => :participants

end
```

Comment: `ORDER BY created_at` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Can you expand on "it is not working"...eg give us an example of what it looks like when you use order... sometimes if you explain how things "aren't working" they can help us lead to better solutions that do work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many records you are pulling out, you can also do the sorting in ruby after pulling them out of the database eg

```
transactions = member.payments + member.fees
transactions = transactions.flatten.sort_by(&:created_at)
```

Comment: It is working but rather than this I have create a common table transaction and store records of both table in same one and using rails scope

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I'd use [`ActiveRecord Associations`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) like this:

```
#app/models/member.rb
Class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :payments, -> { order :created_at }
   has_many :fees, -> { order :created_at }
end

#app/models/payment.rb
Class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :member
end

#app/models/fee.rb
Class Fee < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :member
end
```

This *should* give you the ability to pull the associative data you need with it ordered, like this:

```
@member = Member.find 1
@member.payments #-> should be ordered by created_at
```

Comment: It again shows the payments first then fees but i need order by date. Example fee record 1 and fee record 2 is created in 2013 and 2015. payment record 1 and payment record 2 is created in 2012 and 2014. Then order must be like -> payment record 1> order record 1 > payment record 2 and then fee record 2

Comment: Hmm so it doesn't work correctly? Can you give me some context as to why you require this type of setup?

Comment: It is more similar to debits and credits in the bank statements. Fees may be like credits and Payments like debit. Now we have to print a bank statement like structure.

Comment: Hmm okay, so you're basically trying to create a bank statement with fees & debits in chronological order?

Comment: Might be worth doing a class method for this - if you give me an update, I'll see what I can come up with